# Sqlite: multiple update (find and replace) case insensitive

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, collate

I use DB Browser for SQLite to visualize and update an sqlite file.

I am able to do run a case sensitive query to update some text like this:

```
UPDATE itemNotes  SET note = REPLACE(note ,  'sometext', 'abc');
```

But I would like to match replace all case combinations of `sometext` (e.g. `sometext`, `SOMEtext`, `SOmeText`...)

I tried to do this :

```
UPDATE itemNotes  SET note = REPLACE(LOWER(note),  'sometext', 'abc');
```

But this transform the whole content of the field `note` in lower case which isn't what I want.

I also tried these query but without success:

```
UPDATE itemNotes  SET note = REPLACE(note, BINARY 'sometext', 'abc')
UPDATE itemNotes  SET note = REPLACE(note, COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS'sometext', 'abc')
```

I am doing it on the zotero.sqlite, which is created by this [file](https://github.com/zotero/zotero/blob/26056c87f1d0b31dc56981adaabcab8fc2f85294/resource/schema/userdata.sql)   (line 85).
The table is created by this query

```
CREATE TABLE itemNotes (
    itemID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    parentItemID INT,
    note TEXT,
    title TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES items(itemID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (parentItemID) REFERENCES items(itemID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Please provide a tailored toy database, i.e. a few lines of "create ..." and "insert ...". Consider using the `.dump` from commandline tool.

Comment: @Yunnosch, thanks for your help, please see the edit in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search substring in `LOWER(note)`, but replace it in original. 
I don't know where you getting sometext from, assume that you can check it's length.
In following example I'll use constant.

```sql
UPDATE itemNotes  
SET 
  note = SUBSTR(note, 0, INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext')) || 'abc' || SUBSTR(note, INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext')+sometext_len)
WHERE 
  INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext') >= 0;
```

!Note: It will work only for one replace at a time.

Comment: Thanks for this but I think you missed the closing `(` of the first `SUBSTR`. Is is just before `|| 'abc'` or at the end of the line?

Answer (score 0):

Nosyara answer works great but it only removes 1 instance at a time.

I also tried this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56341931/3154274):

```
UPDATE itemNotes  
SET 
  note = SUBSTR(note, 0, INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext')) || 'abc' || SUBSTR(note, INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext')+sometext_len)
WHERE 
  note LIKE "%sometext%";
```

But when I have many occurence of `sometext` in a field `note`, then only the first on is removed. Based on a comment on this question, I ended up using python to replace the sqlite, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56349346/3154274)