# Repeat a command while true or x times (equivalent of while/for loop)

Tags: sqlite

I would like to repeat this command as many times as there is still `sometext`in the field `note` (several rows from the table `itemNotes` could have one or more `sometext` in the field `note`):

```
UPDATE itemNotes  
SET 
  note = SUBSTR(note, 0, INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext')) || 'abc' || SUBSTR(note, INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext')+sometext_len)
WHERE 
  INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext') >= 0;
```

So a proto-code would be :

```
While (SELECT * FROM itemNotes  WHERE note like "%sometext%") >1

    UPDATE itemNotes  
    SET 
      note = SUBSTR(note, 0, INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext')) || 'abc' || SUBSTR(note, INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext')+sometext_len)
    WHERE 
      INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext') >= 0;
END
```

But apparently `Sqlite3` doesn't support While loop or for loop. They can be emulated with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50306716/3154274) but I have difficulties integrating what I want with this query:

```
    WITH b(x,y) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1,2 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT x+ 1, y + 1 

    FROM b 
    WHERE x < 20
) SELECT * FROM b;
```

Any idea how to do this?

PS: I don't use `replace` because I want to replace all the case combinations of `sometext` (e.g. `sometext`, `SOMEtext`, `SOmeText`...) cf this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243026/3154274)

---

**Current input and desired output:**

For a single row, a note field could look like (and many rows in the table `itemNotes`could look like this one):

```
There is SOmetext and also somETExt and more SOMETEXT and even more sometext
```

The query should output:

```
There is abc and also abc and more abc and even more abc
```

---

I am doing it on the zotero.sqlite, which is created by [this](https://github.com/zotero/zotero/blob/26056c87f1d0b31dc56981adaabcab8fc2f85294/resource/schema/userdata.sql) file (line 85). The table is created by this query

```
CREATE TABLE itemNotes (
    itemID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    parentItemID INT,
    note TEXT,
    title TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES items(itemID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (parentItemID) REFERENCES items(itemID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Why don't you use the built in REPLACE function?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this: it's because I want to match all the case combination of `sometext` cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243026/3154274

Comment: @CaiusJard, I tried this `UPDATE itemNotes  SET note = REPLACE(note ,  'sometext', 'abc') COLLATE NOCASE;` but this query only replace the lowercase occurence of sometext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have your answer in your query:

```
UPDATE itemNotes  
SET 
  note = SUBSTR(note, 0, INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext')) || 'abc' || SUBSTR(note, INSTR(LOWER(note), 'sometext')+sometext_len)
WHERE 
  note LIKE "%sometext%";
```

It will update all rows that contain `sometext` in the `note` field

**UPDATE**

If you want to update the field which has multiple occurrences in different cases and maintain the rest of the text the simplest solution imo is to use `regex` and for that you need an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877856/replace-a-part-of-a-string-with-regexp-in-sqlite3)

```
UPDATE itemNotes  
SET 
  note = regex_replace('\bsometext\b',note,'abc')
WHERE 
  note LIKE "%sometext%";
```

Comment: Thanks for this but your query only replace the first instance in each row. However, I have many `sometext` in each row.

Comment: @MagTun you mean you have multiple occurrences of `sometext` in the `note` field?

Comment: @MagTun it will be helpful if you added and example : input and desire output

Comment: Yes. To be sure, in the table `itemNotes` I could have 100 rows that each have 50+ `sometext` in the field `note`.

Comment: Stephan, I have add an example of input and output in my question. Sorry for not being more precise from the beginning

Comment: @MagTun my advice is that if u cannot make the extension work just do the replace in any scripting language like : php, python, bash etc

Comment: Thanks Stephan, but why such a basic feature is so difficult (or as you imply impossible) to do in Sqlite3?

Comment: @MagTun well its simple sqllite its a lightweight db used to do simple things so it makes sense to not have advance features like this one if you need them then just use mysql :) which has a replace regex function built in

Answer (score 1):

As recommended by Stephan in his last comment, I used python to do this.

Here is my code :

```
import sqlite3
import re
keyword = "sometext"
replacement = "abc"

db = sqlite3.connect(path_to_sqlite)
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM itemNotes  WHERE note like "%{keyword}%"')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    row_regex = re.compile(re.escape(keyword), re.IGNORECASE)
    row_regex_replaced = row_regex.sub(replacement, row[2])

    rowID = row[0]
    sql = "REPLACE INTO itemNotes (itemID,note) VALUES (?,?)"
    data = (rowID, row_regex_replaced)
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
    db.commit()
```