# Python: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error (updating sqlite3 field with html source code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I would like to change all the occurence of `sometext` (matching all case combination like `sometext`, `SOMETEXT`, `SOmeTExt`) in the `note` field of the table `itemNotes` of a sqlite.

Because sqlite doesn't support case insensitive update (I already ask 2 question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56242338/3154274) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56341530/3154274) ), I am using `python` and `regex`.

But I get this error : `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error` matching line of `cursor.execute(f'REPLACE`

I dont' have a `<`in my code so I think it's coming from the `note` field which contains html source code.

Here is my code:

```
keyword ="sometext"
replacement_word="abc"

# load sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect(path_to_sqlite)
cursor = db.cursor()

# search for all therm
cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM itemNotes  WHERE note like "%{keyword}%"')
print("\nfetch one:")
# itemID_list = cursor.fetchone()

# pour chacun des result, change
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    # print(each)
    row_regex = re.compile(re.escape(keyword), re.IGNORECASE)
    row_regex_replaced = row_regex.sub(replacement_word, row[2])

    rowindex = row[0]
    cursor.execute(
        f'REPLACE INTO itemNotes (note) VALUES ({row_regex_replaced}) where itemID = {rowindex}')
```

---

After looking up "sql injection", this is what I came up with :

```
sql = "REPLACE INTO itemNotes (note) VALUES (?) where itemID = (?)"
data = (row_regex_replaced, rowindex,)
cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

But now I am getting this error : `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "where": syntax error`

Comment: Look up "SQL injection"

Comment: @Shawn, thanks for this, I change my code to protect it against sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html):

> The REPLACE command is an alias for the "INSERT OR REPLACE" variant of
>   the INSERT command.

An `INSERT` doesn't have a `WHERE` clause. The query needs to be written as a "regular" INSERT, and the system will "decide" whether to replace. Something like `INSERT into itemNotes (itemID,note) VALUES (?,?)`. (NB the order of the `data` list in the above example would need to change).